# Google Service Account permission denied gmail pub/sub Golang

Tags: go, push-notification, google-api, gmail-api, watch

Trying to create an application that updates links in my domains emails. I have got the service account element working, and can retrieve all the email accounts in my domain on Google Apps.

So with

```
  config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly")
```

I create a new admin object, and `srv.Users.List()` giving me the users.

I now want to start a `watch` on each account so that Gmail can push emails to my app.

To do this, I need an access token and the impersonate the email address of the account I want to start the watch on.

```
   ctx := context.Background()
    tokenSource := config.TokenSource(ctx)
    token, err := tokenSource.Token()
```

where config comes from `JWTConfigFromJSON` earlier.

It attemps to make the `watch` request, but I get the error `googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions`

First issue: I'm not sure I can get the token like this, do I have to have a seperate oAuth config and then use that to get the token? (That would surely require user interaction).

Second issue: I suspect I have not set the correct permissions, in either the code, or in the Service Account, but I'm not sure what they should be

Last issue: in the `JWTConfigFromJSON` call, When I remove the gmail scope, it it successfully gets a token. When I put it back I get `"Unauthorized client or scope in request."`

Any help greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: If anyone is wondering the solution turned out to be in the end user domain account. The gmail permission was missing from there. Please comment if you would like to see a working version of this, and I'll make a gist of it